# Django TypeError: 'formas_pago' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, one-to-many

I'm trying to keep all information in one JSON object. If I delete the relationship "establecimientos" function, no errors errors are thrown, but if I include "establecimientos" I get the following error.

> Error: TypeError: 'formas_pago' is an invalid keyword argument for
>   this function

This error occurs on the line: `negocio = Negocio.objects.create(**validated_data)` of my Serializer class

**Serializer Class**

This is the serializadora class work correctly until this line (establecimientos_data = validated_data.pop('establecimientos'))

```
class NegocioSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    establecimientos = EstablecimientoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Negocio
        fields = ('id','nombre', 'slug', 'fecha_creado', 'tipos_negocio','formas_pago', 'propietario', 'establecimientos')
        read_only_fields = ('propietario',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        establecimientos_data = validated_data.pop('establecimientos')
        negocio = Negocio.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for establecimiento_data in establecimientos_data:
            Establecimiento.objects.create(negocio=negocio, **establecimiento_data)
        return negocio
```

**Models Class**

```
class Negocio(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        logo = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_logo_to)
        fecha_creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        propietario = models.ForeignKey(User)
        tipos_negocio = models.ManyToManyField('TipoNegocio')
        formas_pago = models.ManyToManyField('FormaPago')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre

        def get_establecimiento(self):
            establecimientos = Establecimiento.objects.filter(negocio=self)
            return establecimientos


    class TipoNegocio(models.Model):
        tipo = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.tipo

    class Establecimiento(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        direccion = models.TextField()
        telefono = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        negocio = models.ForeignKey('Negocio', related_name='establecimientos')

        def __str__(self):
            return u'{0} - {1}'.format(self.negocio, self.nombre)


        def get_horarios(self):
            horarios = Horario.objects.filter(establecimiento=self)
            return horarios

    class FormaPago(models.Model):
        forma_pago =  models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.forma_pago
```

**JSON**

```
{
        "nombre": "nuevo",
        "slug": "nuev",
        "tipos_negocio": [
            2,
            3
         ],
        "formas_pago": [
            1
         ],
        "establecimientos": [{
                        "nombre": "Matriz",
                        "direccion": "asasasas",
                        "telefono": "0997739485",
                        "horarios": []
                    },
                    {
                        "nombre": "bbb",
                        "direccion": "sassdd",
                        "telefono": "445588",
                        "horarios": []
                    }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ManyToManyField` data cannot be populated like other fields. They have to be added to the field. Eg)

```
formas_pago = validated_data.pop('formas_pago', [])
formas_pago = FormaPago.objects.filter(id__in=formas_pago)
negocio = Negocio.objects.create(**validated_data)
negocio.formas_pago.add(*negocio)
```

Thus, you have to get all the objects in a list, and add it to the `formas_pago` field

Comment: thanks, this could be the solution, but why when they are only the ManyToMany, django knows how to save ?. In this example if I remove "Establecimiento" of the model "Negocio" if added "forma_pago" automatically.